# [R]Fuzzy C-Means, different between ppclust vs e1071?

Tags: r, fuzzy-logic

no. of cluster = 10, data points = 6000

```
library(ppclust)
cm <- fcm(x,centers = cen)
```

takes ~ 10 minutes

```
library(e1071)
cm <- cmeans(x,cen,1000)
```

takes ~ 1 minute

the only reason I prefer ppclust is because it allows nstart, meaning I am not stuck with local optima.

Given both are doing same thing, why is one taking 10x time then other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the source code. The guts of `e1071::cmeans` are written in C, but `ppclust::fcm` looks like all R and has some ugly looking `eval` stuff which might make it dead slow.